# awk select columns from input list

Tags: parsing, csv, awk

I'd like an awk script to select the columns from a file based on a list of columns in another file. For example:

```
$cat cols
3 2 6 4

$cat text
a b c d e f g
h i j k l m n

$awk_script cols text
c b f d
j i m k
```

So the 3rd, 2nd, 6th and fourth columns have been selected in that order.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{n=split($0,c);next}{for(i=1;i<n;i++){printf "%s%s", $c[i], OFS};print ""}' cols text
```

We are passing two input files to awk, first the cols then the text. `awk` counts the number of input lines processed in the internal variable `NR`. `FNR` is the record number in the current file. When reading the first (and only) line of `cols` `NR` and `FNR` have a value of `1` meaning the following block gets executed.

`{n=split($0,c);next}` splits the whole line which is stored in `$0` into the the array `c` using the global field delimiter and saves the number of columns to print in `n`. We will later use `n` in a for loop. `next` tells `awk` to stop processing the current line and read the next line of input.

The block `{for(i=1;i<=n+1;i++){printf "%s",$c[i],OFS};print ""}` gets executed on all other lines since it is not prefixed with a condition. The `for` loop iterates through `cols` and prints the corresponding columns delimited by the *output file separator* `OFS`. Finally we print a new line.

Output:

```
c b f d
j i m k
```

Comment: Never do a printf with input data in the format field (`printf $c[i]`), use the full printf synopsis instead, `printf "%s", $c[i]`. Imagine the difference if `$c[i]` contained a printf formatting string, e.g. `%s`. You're missing printing OFS between fields. The loop should end at `<=n`, not `<n+1` for clarity and efficiency. Also, you should use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"` as it's briefer and uses whatever value ORS is set to instead of hard-coding the same value.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the advices. Much appreciated! I've edited it. The solution adds now and additonal `OFS` at the end of every line, but it should be good enough since OFS is a space.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{n=split($0,f);next} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' cols text
c b f d
j i m k
```